# Is there an elegant way of checking in C++ if the library complex was included?

Tags: c++, header, portability, guard

I'm working on a C++ library, and I want to compile some functions only if the library complex was included, in the main file.
I'm considering using the macro the complex library defines to use as a guard, check if it was defined, and proceed if yes.
Checking the library complex header in the intel and GNU compilers I observed that they define different macros, namely *INC_COMPLEX*(intel) and _GLIBCXX_COMPLEX(GNU). Using this information I could write the following working example:

```
#include <complex>
    
#if ((defined(_INC_COMPLEX_) || defined(_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX)))
    #define _complex_probe 1
#endif

#include <iostream>

int main(int args, char** argv){

#if _complex_probe                                                                      
        std::cout << " Library complex included. \n";
#endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a more elegant or portable way to implement this resource?

Comment: Why do you need this? Since inclusion order of independent libraries in C++ is generally expected to be irrelevant, this seems like a potentially quite bad idea. Instead, why not provide the `complex` supporting part of your library inside a separate header file which, in turn, includes the relevant standard header?

Comment: FYI. (since `std::complex` is a template) any function declared like `template<typename T> void foo(const std::complex<T>&) {...}` is already guaranteed to only "exist" if a user actually uses it.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. My question was more in the direction of learning. For this, I was performing tests in a small personal library I use to test this kind of unusual idea. I don't have a direct application, I just wanted to explore the idea.